# Wind Speed to affect larger creatures in Pathfinder 1e

Tags: pathfinder-1e

On the page for [Weather (wind)](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/environment/weather/#Wind), it specifies at what point medium creatures get blown away by wind.  51+mph.

An F1 tornado is 73-112mph, which is a large range entirely above that threshold.

Is there a chart to measure the wind speeds required to knock larger creatures out of the sky/lift off the ground (say, dragons)

Answer (score 3):

### Archives of Nethys has an expanded table

The [Weather](https://aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Weather&Category=Environment) page of the SRD sanctioned by Paizo has an extended table including:

> Wind Force | Wind Speed | Normal/Siege Weapons | **Checked Size | Blown Away** | Fly Penalty
> [...]
> Hurricane | 75-174 mph | Impossible/—4 | **Large | Medium** | -12
> Tornado | 175-300 mph | Impossible/Impossible | **Huge - Large** | -16

The lower wind speeds are also adjusted up somewhat (e.g. Windstorm is 51-74 MPH).

Comment: This answer is yet another example of why you should always use the AoN for your pathfinder SRD needs :)